# facebook register - how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Although I am not new to programming or API's, I'm quite new to facebook API. This plugin uses some facebook code, and it's clearly not working.

I have following code on my registration page. However, the "register using facebook" is not clickable. This is what firebug shows: `<fb:login-button scope="email,user_about_me,user_location"></fb:login-button>`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId  : '<?php echo $ap_info['appId']; ?>',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : <?php echo $ap_info['cookie']; ?>, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
                oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
              });

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
            };
            (function() {
              var e = document.createElement('script');
              e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
              e.async = true;
              document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
            </script>
```

All the variables like appId, cookie etc have proper values. I debugged through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "official" sample code which is provided here?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#quickstart